# iTextPdf - Writing on same page's copy multiple times and merging them

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a pdf template on which I have to write, say the number of person visited a place along with other information. The pdf template has 25 rows.
So, if the count of people visiting the place is more than 25, I need to append a copy of the same pdf template as page 2 which will contain the entry for person 26 till 50. My current set up is :

```
 reader = new PdfReader(PATH_TO_PDF_TEMPLATE);
 stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, WRITTEN_FILE_PATH);
```

I want to use the same PDF Template again and append to the written 1st page in case the number of people is more than 25.

Comment: so you have a table has 25 row  on the pdf?

Comment: yes, which I will be appending for every 25 entries @krezus

Comment: Itext table can generate next page to fill table for all data. Maybe you just need to calculate size of pdf page and set row size to fix 25 entries per page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of table which has 21 rows per page. You can set `cell.setFixedHeight(33.68f)` (*bigger than 33.68*) cell height to get 25 rows per page.

```
   public class SimpleTable {
    public static final String DEST = "C:\\Users\\krezus\\Desktop\\simple_table.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new SimpleTable5().createPdf(DEST);
    }
    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);
        System.out.println(PageSize.A4.getHeight()/25);
        table.setSkipLastFooter(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 350; i++) {
                PdfPCell celltable = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Integer.toString(i)));
                celltable.setFixedHeight(33.68f);
                table.addCell(celltable);

        }
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used PdfPageEvent.onStartPage() and onEndPage().

```
  writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, exportOutputStream);
  writer.setPageEvent(pageEventHandler);
```